# Actionbar custom style with title highlight on clicked

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar

I have a quick question regarding custom style navigation in the action bar.

I have used this code to create a custom title layout:

```
ActionBar ab = getActionBar();
ab.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
ab.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
View customTitle = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_title, null);

ab.setCustomView(customTitle);
```

which looks like this:
[image: Huzzah, looks great.]

But when I click the navigate up button, only the icon and the indicator highlight... like this:
[image: subtle highlight]

I'm looking for a way to get the whole title clickable, but with the custom layout. Is this possible?

For reference here is my actionbar layout XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Ferries"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:id="@+id/actionbar_title_depart" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text=""
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:id="@+id/actionbar_title_arrive" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks for taking a look, and I look forward to hear some suggestions!